# ScrapySlash "masks" 404

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have some issues trying to manage 404 responses with my spider. It seems that ScrapySlash is masking 404 response with 200.

Here's my code

```
def buildRequest(self, url, dbid):
     request = Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                  'splash': {
                      'args':{
                          'html': 1,
                          'wait': 5
                          },
                      'magic_response':True,
                      },
                 'dbId': dbid
                  }, errback=self.errback_httpbin, dont_filter=True)
     return request
```

A simple `print response.status` will always show 200. Testing my url with `scrapy shell` will display `response <404 http://www.foo.com/>`

When I'm using a Request object my spider will go to `self.errback_httpbin` method but using a SpaslRequest it won't. The SlashRequest handles 502 correctly but not 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can only achieve this with the `/execute` response in conjunction with "magic responses" (that are ON by default):

> `meta['splash']['magic_response']` - when set to True and a JSON
>   response is received from Splash, several attributes of the response
>   (headers, body, url, status code) are filled using data returned in
>   JSON:
>
> - response.headers are filled from '`headers`' keys;
> - response.url is set
>     to the value of '`url`' key;
> - response.body is set to the value of '`html`'
>     key, or to base64-decoded value of 'body' key;
> - response.status is set
>     to the value of '`http_status`' key. (...)
>
> This option is set to `True` by default if you use `SplashRequest`.

Other endpoints like `/render.html` and `/render.json` will return 502 Bad Gateway for 4xx and 5xx responses from remote servers (to be checked).

Building on this [example Lua script from the README](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash):

```
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
    })
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response
  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
  }
end
```

(notice the table at the end, returning url, headers, http_status, html and cookies.)

... when you use this script with `/execute`, `SplashRequest` and errbacks, you can reproduce the [errback example from Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing):

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError

from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
    })
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response
  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
  }
end
"""

class ErrbackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "errback_example"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.httpbin.org/",              # HTTP 200 expected
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/404",    # Not found error
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/500",    # server issue
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(u, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                                   errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                                   endpoint='execute',
                                   args={'lua_source': script})

    def parse_httpbin(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Got successful response from {}'.format(response.url))
        # do something useful here...

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
        # you may need the failure's type:

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Running that with scrapy 1.3, this is what you get:

```
$ scrapy crawl errback_example
2017-01-11 18:07:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: test404)
(...)
2017-01-11 18:07:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
(...)
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/404 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [errback_example] ERROR: <twisted.python.failure.Failure scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpError: Ignoring non-200 response>
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [errback_example] ERROR: HttpError on http://www.httpbin.org/status/404
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/ via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://www.httpbin.org/status/500 via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [errback_example] INFO: Got successful response from http://www.httpbin.org/
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [errback_example] ERROR: <twisted.python.failure.Failure scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpError: Ignoring non-200 response>
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [errback_example] ERROR: HttpError on http://www.httpbin.org/status/500
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 5365,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 17332,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11, 17, 7, 21, 715440),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 8,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 8,
 'splash/execute/request_count': 3,
 'splash/execute/response_count/200': 1,
 'splash/execute/response_count/400': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11, 17, 7, 20, 683232)}
2017-01-11 18:07:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The `[errback_example] ERROR` lines show when the errback is called, i.e. here you get the 404 and 500 passing through the errback method.

Comment: Thank you very much